# Assets in JavaScript - Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I've got a problem, I am using [Head.js](http://headjs.com/) plugin to import several js files in my template. Each file has a normal path e.g. `assets/js/clock/date.js`

The problem is that neither I can use the path directly in importing nor using the twig `asset()` function to get path to these files. As an example this is what I have in a separate js file

```
head.js("../assets/js/newsticker/jquery.newsTicker.js", function() { ... });
```

How can I get access to the files in folder assets inside a `javascript` file?

Comment: Provide your code; Why you cannot use `asset()` function? I guess you are referencing those javascript file in a twig file

Comment: for example I've got something like that:
<!-- language: lang-js -->
head.js("../assets/js/newsticker/jquery.newsTicker.js", function() {
    var nt_title = $('#nt-title').newsTicker({
        row_height: 18,
        max_rows: 1,
        duration: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: 0
    });
});

Comment: Edit your question and show us your current code, where you are importing the JavaScript files.

Comment: how can I format js code to show you?

Comment: Indent your code by 4 spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: where this `heade.js()` code is used? In your twig file?

Comment: Edit your top first question and put everything you have your code, till we understand what exactly you need; otherwise we won't be able to help you. Also as I said where do you use this `head.js()`, is it in your twig file?

Comment: It is not used in twig file, it is js library http://headjs.com/ and it should load another file.

Comment: Sorry I cannot format my post in right way, I've pasted my code here http://wklej.to/LVFVO generally I want to get the path to file in symfony's enviromental

Comment: OK, now it's more clear; What you need is a global javascript defined in your twig which contains the path of whatever you want to load; for example `var generalPath = "{{ asset('path/to/your/asset') }}";` now you can call the function as `header.js(generalPath + 'jquery.cookie.js')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a global javascript defined variable in your twig which contains the path of whatever you want to load; for example

```
var generalPath = "{{ asset('path/to/your/asset') }}";
```

now you can call the function as `header.js` by concatenating with the defined global variable as

```
head.js(generalPath + 'jquery.cookie.js');
```